# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes'

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error while bundling a React Native project with new architecture with version 0.69.1

```
> Task :ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes FAILED
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:42 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
```